# How to pivot the table (BigQuery) in this case without listing all categories manually?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I have a table where the schema is roughly the following:

```
user_id | segment_id | day
```

The range of values for `segment_id` is not small: from 1 to 70.
For `day`, it's 0-2.

Ideally, I would like to transform this table to

```
user_id | segment_1_day_1_count | segment_2_day_1_count | ... segment_70_day_1_count | ... | segment_70_day_3_count | ... segment_1_count | segment_2_count | segment_3_count | day_1_count | day_2_count | day_3_count | total_count
```

Roughly speaking, for each `user_id` I want to get counts for all breakdown combinations:

- by segment
- by day
- by segment and day
- total

That looks very much like pivoting, but I am not sure there is a way to pivot based on several columns.

My current attempt is the following:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  segment_id,
  day,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, segment_id),
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, day),
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, segment_id, day),
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)
FROM some_table
```

This is the data I need, but not in the desired format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate (select '''select * from your_table 
pivot (count(*) for 'segment_' || segment_id || '_day_' || day || '_count' in (''' || 
string_agg('"segment_' || segment_id || '_day_' || day || '_count"', ',' order by day, segment_id) || '))'
from (select distinct segment_id from your_table),
(select distinct day from your_table));
```

if applied to dummy data similar to what you described  - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That does exactly what I needed in terms of the `segment x day` product. But is it possible to also add counts for `segment`, `day` and `total` separately? I mean, in addition to the result your query yields, to have `segment_x_count`, `day_0_count`, `total_count`. It seems that adding another `pivot` is not allowed in one query?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to also add counts for segment, day and total separately?

Sure. just [relatively] simple extension of my originally proposed solution

```
execute immediate (select '''
  select * from (
    select * 
    from your_table 
    pivot (count(*) for 'segment_' || segment_id || '_day_' || day || '_count' in (''' || list1 || '''))
  ) 
  join (
    select * 
    from (select * except(day) from your_table) 
    pivot (count(*) for 'segment_' || segment_id || '_count' in (''' || list2 || '''))
  )
  using(user_id)
  join (
    select * 
    from (select * except(segment_id) from your_table) 
    pivot (count(*) for 'day_' || day || '_count' in (''' || list3 || '''))
  )
  using(user_id)
  join (
    select user_id, count(*) total 
    from your_table
    group by user_id
  )
  using(user_id)
'''
from (
  select string_agg('"segment_' || segment_id || '_day_' || day || '_count"', ',' order by day, segment_id) list1
  from (select distinct segment_id from your_table), (select distinct day from your_table)
),(
  select string_agg('"segment_' || segment_id || '_count"', ',' order by segment_id) list2
  from (select distinct segment_id from your_table)
),(
  select string_agg('"day_' || day || '_count"', ',' order by day) list3
  from (select distinct day from your_table)
) 
)
```

if applied to dummy data similar to what you described - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such an outstanding and detailed answer.